# Stumped with a transient population program in c++

Tags: c++

this is my first time posting on here. Whenever I've gotten stuck on a programming problem, I've typically been able to find enough information to get me unstuck. I'm afraid that the issue I'm having though, I can't quite find an answer to. It's something I'd need someone to look at to tell me what I may be doing wrong in my code.

I have the program running successfully, and it DOES work. The issue however, is that my produced output is off by a few numbers when compared to the expected output on My Programming Lab. I'm really not sure of what to do to produce the correct output. Allow me to post both my source code, and a screenshot MPL's results screen.

**SOURCE CODE:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int populationCalculator(int, double, double, int, int);

int main()
{
    int startingPopulation, newArrivals, peopleWhoLeft, years, 
    newPopulation, finalPopulation;

    double deathRate, birthRate;

    cout << "This program calculates population change.\n";
    cout << "Enter the starting population size: ";
    cin >> startingPopulation;
    while (startingPopulation < 2)
    {
        cout << "\nThe starting population may not be less than two. Please 
                   re - enter: ";
        cin >> startingPopulation;
    }

    cout << "Enter the annual birth rate (as % of current population): ";
    cin >> birthRate;
    while (birthRate < 0)
    {
       cout << "\nBirth rate percent cannot be negative. Please re - 
                 enter:";
        cin >> birthRate;
    }
    birthRate = birthRate / 100;

    cout << "Enter the annual death rate (as % of current population): ";
    cin >> deathRate;
    while (deathRate < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nDeath rate percent cannot be negative. Please  re - 
                  enter: ";
        cin >> deathRate;
    }
    deathRate = deathRate / 100;

    cout << "How many individuals move into the area each year? ";
    cin >> newArrivals;
    while (newArrivals < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nArrivals cannot be negative. Please re - enter: ";
        cin >> newArrivals;
    }

    cout << "How many individuals leave the area each year? ";
    cin >> peopleWhoLeft;
    while (peopleWhoLeft < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nDepartures cannot be negative. Please re - enter: ";
        cin >> peopleWhoLeft;
    }

    cout << "For how many years do you wish to view population changes? ";
    cin >> years;
    while (years < 1)
    {
        cout << "\nYears must be one or more. Please re - enter: ";
        cin >> years;
    }

    newPopulation = populationCalculator(startingPopulation, deathRate, 
    birthRate, newArrivals, peopleWhoLeft);

    cout << "\nStarting population: " << startingPopulation << endl;
    for (int loopCount = 1; loopCount <= years; loopCount++)
    {
        newPopulation = populationCalculator(newPopulation, deathRate, 
        birthRate, newArrivals, peopleWhoLeft);

        cout << "Population at the end of year " << loopCount << " is: " << 
        newPopulation << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int populationCalculator(int Population, double deathRate, double birthRate, 
int newArrivals, int peopleWhoLeft)
{
    int newPopulationCount;

    newPopulationCount = Population + (Population * birthRate) - (Population 
  * deathRate) + newArrivals - peopleWhoLeft;

    return newPopulationCount;
}
```

**MPL RESULTS:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNbtl.jpg

I really will appreciate if anyone can help me figure out why my produced output is off by a few numbers.

Comment: Use a debugger and step through your code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the output and what is the expected output? Besides from your question, if you want to do C++, you should really start to work with classes. Imagine if you had `Population population(starting_population, birth_rate, death_rate); for(size_t i = 0; i < years; i++) { population.simulate_year(); population.print_status(); }`

Comment: Does `double populationCalculator(int Population, double deathRate, double birthRate, 
int newArrivals, int peopleWhoLeft) { }` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step through your code. You're returning an int where you have double and int multiplication. Make sure that you aren't truncating values that might need to be rounded up or down.

Does birth happen before or after death? Should it occur in steps, or all at once like you have shown?

Comment: This would be my guess too... but - I would suggest you change your nickname to something less generic.

Comment: This was the issue, but I just wasn't sure of how to exactly solve this. I finally ended up declaring the function as a double, changing the population data type to double, returning a double, and assigning the result to a new int variable for displaying to truncate the number (since you can't have a fraction of a person =P)

My figures were off because of my original truncation, and then passing the truncated value back to the function for new calculations. Keeping the decimals between calculations solved it all. Simple, but damn did it torment me for way longer than it should have.

Answer (score 0):

try casting to a double in your operations that involve doubles and integers. For example

```
birthRate = (double)(birthRate / 100);
deathRate = (double)(deathRate / 100);
```

Sometimes programming languages will cast a double to an integer, which causes your numbers to be off.

Comment: But that would totally mess up his results, because he'll get 0.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the number were rounded off?
I assume this is the case because I noticed you declared some variables in double but the end result is integer. Try to change the data type of the method 
`populationCalculator()`, `newPopulation` and of course the returning values of the method `populationCalculator()` from **int** to **double**.

Comment: No I've tried that, but it didn't work =[. I know the issue has something to do with rounding, but I am having difficulty figuring out exactly how to fix it =|.

Comment: what did you enter exactly to get that output?